# How to call a table using its Id in a javascript with if-else statements

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, spring-mvc

Am trying to show a table using a value "graph". if graph value is 0 then it should display table1(id of table), if value of graph is 10 , it should display table2(id of table). am trying to show this with java script with if else case. i don't know how to call a table within java script in if else statements

```
               <script>
    $(document).ready( function () {

        myFunc();

    });
    function myFunc(){

        console.log("input value", document.getElementById("graph").value)  
        if (document.getElementById('graph').value==00){


        }


    }</script>
```

how to write here to call a table in if else statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing with `Jquery` if possible . Hope it helps !

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   if($('#graph').val()=='00'){
        $('#table1').show();
        $('#table2').hide();
     }else if($('#graph').val()=='10'){
            $('#table2').show();
            $('#table1').hide();
             }
});
```

Comment: can i call this onload in body... or just i can keep and use in Script

Comment: yes... but first person responded first... so i marked him ...sorry for not marking your's

Comment: your's working perfectly... thank you so much  yar... shukriya

Comment: :D :D aapka swagat hai ;)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming both tables are available on the document when the function is called, it should look something like this....

```
<script>
    $(document).ready( function () {
    myFunc();
});

function myFunc(){
    console.log("input value", document.getElementById("graph").value);
    var val = document.getElementById("graph").value;
    document.getElementById('table1').style.display = val== 0 ? '' : 'none';
    document.getElementById('table2').style.display = val== 10 ? '' : 'none';
}</script>
```

if you want to do it in a if else if....

```
    //First hide both tables
    document.getElementById('table1').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('table2').style.display = 'none';
    var val = document.getElementById("graph").value;

    //then show the one we want
    if(val==0)
        document.getElementById('table1').style.display = '';
    else if(val == 10)
        document.getElementById('table2').style.display = '';
```

Hope that helps

Comment: in console input value 0
listPayout.htm (line 1196)
2
TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null
 

document.getElementById('tableId1').style.display = 'none';

Comment: you have a typo... replace document.getElementById('tableId1').style.display = 'none'; with document.getElementById('table1').style.display = 'none'; (remove the Id in the string 'tableId1')

Answer (score 0):

Try this one...it has been tested...

```
    jQuery(document).ready( function () {
       myFunc();
    });
   function myFunc()
   {

            console.log("input value", document.getElementById("test").value);  
             if (document.getElementById('test').value=="testing"){

                alert("got in if");
             }

            else 
           {
            //this will hit the column of a table now change it according to your requirements
           //you may write $ instead of jQuery,I assigned a value to a column you set it as you need...
          jQuery("#your_target_id_in_table").val("hello"); 
          alert(jQuery("#your_target_id_in_table").val()); //you may write $ instead of jQuery
          }


  }
```